# wallet.dat corrupt. Try using the wallet tool bitcoin-wallet to salvage or restoring a backup

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

I'm trying to restore an old wallet, using bitcoin-qt 0.21 but I'm getting the following error on startup: *wallet.dat corrupt. Try using the wallet tool bitcoin-wallet to salvage or restoring a backup*

What tool is this? I have tried googling it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

bitcoin-wallet is a tool distributed along with Bitcoin Core. The package contains several binaries, including `bitcoin-qt`, `bitcoind`, `bitcoin-cli`, but also a few stand-alone tools like `bitcoin-tx` and `bitcoin-wallet`.